# Parse push notifications error reporting

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform

I am implementing parse into our system and using the REST Api for sending Push notifications to devices. This works successfully however we would like to have some reporting on notifications that failed to be delivered to the device.

Parse has the api.parse.com/1/events/Error api call but it is not clear as to what the errors would pertain too, it seems like events(a push is an event).

My goal is to have a record of failed pushes and to re-send a push notification if a device for some reasons failed to receive it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.